# Set Location in BIM360 Quality issue via API? (Rather than Location Details)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I am able to add **Quality Issues** through the BIM360 API (or associated APIs, link below) and I am able to set the **Location Details**. However, my customer uses the **Location** field, not Location Details. Is there any way to set the Location, specifically?

Here is the page for posting an item:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-POST/

I don't see a location attribute or a location permitted attribute, just location details.

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OmZd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the location id under the path `attributes.lbs_location`

```json
{
    "id": "038edfcf-t56y-4e04-a358-42c95f20c945",
    "type": "quality_issues",
    //...
    "attributes": {
        //...
        "lbs_location": "d14ce3a6-e61b-4ab0-a9be-5acf7b5366df",
        //...
    },
    // ... 
}
```

To get corresponding location data, we need to call [GET v2/containers/{containerId}/trees/{treeId}/nodes](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/locations-nodes-GET/)

```json
{
  "pagination": {
    "limit": 2,
    "offset": 0,
    "totalResults": 2,
    "nextUrl": null
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "5add4375-f223-4201-88b9-8049e68416aa",
      "parentId": null,
      "type": "Root",
      "name": "Project",
      "description": "Project description",
      "barcode": null,
      "order": 0,
      "documentCount": 0,
      "areaDefined": false
    },
    {
      "id": "d14ce3a6-e61b-4ab0-a9be-5acf7b5366df",
      "parentId": "5add4375-f223-4201-88b9-8049e68416aa",
      "type": "Area",
      "name": "Area 1",
      "description": "An Area 1 node",
      "barcode": "ABC123",
      "order": 0,
      "documentCount": 2,
      "areaDefined": true
    }
  ]
}
```

To modify the location id for a quality issue, we can call [PATCH issues/:id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-:id-PATCH/) with the below payload:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "type": "quality_issues",
        "id": "038edfcf-t56y-4e04-a358-42c95f20c945",
        "attributes": {
            "lbs_location": "d14ce3a6-e61b-4ab0-a9be-5acf7b5366df"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so in order to get the location(s) in the location tree, the location(s) must already exist... I can certainly make the /nodes call this to get a list of "pre-existing" locations; but if they don't exist, is there an API call to create them?

Comment: As I know, API for creating location nodes is coming, please bear with us. Once it gets released, we will post an announcement on Forge Website. Thank you for your patience!